# Changes in Instances in 'view.py' won't reflect in pages in Flask

Tags: python, multithreading, web, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I've created in my 'view.py' program (HTML redirector) a thread responsible to update my instances that contains data from DB. The idea is that every 15 seconds the data from DB is refreshed in these instances so when the user refreshes the HTML page, the data is available.

Code:

```
#defining the Thread Function
def set_global_vars():
while True:
    global  ALL_SERVERS_FROM_DB
    time.sleep(15)
    ALL_SERVERS_FROM_DB = ServersManipulator(Server().query_all())       

set_vars_thread = threading.Thread(target=set_global_vars)
set_vars_thread .start()   

# Redirecting to servers page uging ALL_SERVERS_FROM_DB
@page.route('/servers', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def servers(server='ALL'):
    return render_template('servers.html', server_man=ALL_SERVERS_FROM_DB, server=server)
```

Problem is if I add a new entry that should affect 'ALL_SERVERS_FROM_DB', it doesn't reflect on the HTML page, that uses this instance to populate a table.

Hope I was clear and that someone can help me.

Kind Regards

Comment: Does the data appear updated if you reload the page?

Comment: @DoctorAgon No, that is exactly my problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, 
It turns out I must recreate my DB Engine session every time I query from DB, otherwise, it seems it uses some kind of cache.

```
    def query_all(self):
    """
    Purpose:
        Retrieves all entries related to this Class from Database 
    Parameters:
    """
    global DBSession
    DBSession = sessionmaker(bind=DBENGINE)() #  <- I've added this to work 
    result = DBSession.query(type(self)).order_by(type(self).id)
    DBSession.close()
    return result
```

Before I was only starting the DBsession when the Object was instantiated.

Regards